# matlab parallel computing toolbox--failed to start matlabpool using 'local' profile

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

My desktop runs in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and the matlab is R2013a. I'm doing local parallel computing(use multicores of my desktop).
Before using the following command to start matlabpool, I've already validated the local configuration of parallel computing toolbox. To verify this point, I've attached the figure 1.

[image]

```
                                    figure 1

  matlabpool local 4
```

But it takes like forever to start the matlabpool. After running 10 minutes, the command line is still like:

> Starting matlabpool using the 'local' profile ...

So I use ctrl+c to stop it. It always give me:

> Operation terminated by user during
>   parallel.internal.pool.InteractiveClient>iGetSingleConnection   (line
>   737)

Based on the above information, it seems that it get stuck at iGetSingleConnection.

Thanks,

Comment: Same problem. I can't start a pool with more than 2 workers on 2013b but I can on 2013a.

Comment: Are there inbound firewall rules in Ubuntu?  At least in Windows, when I install a new version of MATLAB, I need to create new rules to allow inbound connections to three different MATLAB executables.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Ubuntu, but in Windows when you install a new version of MATLAB, the old firewall rules do not apply to the new executables.  So, you need to open the firewall to allow access to the smpd.exe, mpiexec.exe and MATLAB.exe processes. For example, in Windows, I get one of these:

[image]

Then I need to go into Windows firewall settings and make the rules.  [Here is how to create an inbound program rule in Windows 7/8](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj717295.aspx).  Maybe there is something similar in Ubuntu.